# User mailbox converted to a shared mailbox doesn't work properly

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js

We have converted a user mailbox to a shared mailbox using `convert to shared mailbox` option which is available in M365 admin portal.
[image]

Once we convert it to a shared mailbox, officeJS APIs returns undefined mail item.
[image]

We have customers who are using this option to convert an user mailbox to shared mailbox but getting above error. Is there any solution to properly convert an user mailbox to a shared mailbox?

The OfficeJS APIs should return a valid object on `Office.context.mailbox.item` instead of undefined.
We tried with a new shared mailbox which is not converted from an user mailbox and on that shared mailbox OfficeJS is returning a valid object on `Office.context.mailbox.item`.